# Metal bar on DMM PCB

Tags: pcb, identification

What is this large metal bar inside my DMMs? One of them labeled it `ST`. They appear to be connected to the `COM` port or fuse. Is this just a big jumper for the 10 A ammeter?[image: Metal bars in DMM]

Comment: Yet another [picture of a shunt in a DMM](https://makersconfidential.blogspot.com/2015/06/teardown-of-mastech-ms8268-multimeter.html).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

That is **not** a simple jumper.

That is the precision resistor used to measure the current.  This is also known as a "shunt" - hence the designation ST for shunt.

You measure current by passing it through a known resistance and measuring the voltage across that resistor.  Using Ohm's law, you can calculate the current from the voltage and the resistance.

If you look closely, you will see that one of them has been trimmed by making nicks in the wire.  That changes the resistance slightly.  You measure a known current with a new meter, then whack on the shunt to make your new meter display the known current.

The thick ones like that are usually for the 10A range.  The lower current shunts are usually small, precision resistors on the board.

Comment: +1 Looks like they might have added a bit of solder to reduce the resistance on the left one,  perhaps overshot with the nick. They're usually solid [Constantan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constantan) wire, which is solderable and has a reasonably low tempco.

Answer (score 8):

It is the current shunt.

Your meter probably has a 200 mV full scale range and will read 10.00 A with 100 mV voltage drop across the shunt. From Ohm's Law we can calculate that the shunt resistance = V/I = 0.1/10 = 0.01 Ω.

A decent meter will have a proper fuse protecting the shunt. The fuses in your photo look too small so be very careful.

Comment: The cheap Micronta 22-181B meter I own has an unfused shunt on a separate input jack.  The jack is clearly labelled 10A MAX UNFUSED on meter to make you think twice about what circuit you're going to put it in series with.  (There's also a separate jack for the 400/40mA current input, on a different fuse from the 4mA / volatage / resistance / capacitance / diode-test input.)  Anyway, probably the OP's meter has an unfused 10A shunt.

Comment: Both the OPs meters appear to have positions for two fuses, suggesting both current inputs are fused. In the right hand picture you can even see the fuseholder labeled as 10A. Whether those fuses (especially the glass ones) are adequate to protect the meter and it's user in the event of reasonablly forseeable misuse (i.e. forgetting the probe is plugged into the current socket and then trying to measure mains voltage) is highly questionable though.

Answer (score 2):

It is a hollow copper tubing or a "cheap & dirty" 1% current shunt resistor for measuring current on the 10A using voltage (specifically mV).

Here's a Murata 0.25% current shunt:

[image: Fancier $20 Resistor]

It costs $20. 
See the difference?

Due to the [Positive Transfer Coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temperature_coefficient) (PTC) characteristic of metal conductors, heat causes the resistance to increase and yield a false rise in voltage sensed as a current.  Generally, voltage drops for current sensing are limited to 50mV for this reason. Additional heatsinks may increase this limit.

Comment: Proper current shunts are made of alloys like Constantan or Manganin that have near zero temperature coefficient over their normal working temperature range, though they can suffer resistance changes if overheated. https://riedon.com/media/pdf/RS.pdf